# How to implement face recognition in an image in .net 3.5?

Tags: c#, image, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5

I need to implement face recognition like in orkut album.

In my website when a user uploads a photo and checks the photo in album I need to implement the feature and place rectangles over the faces in photo like in orkut album like in [this link](http://en.blog.orkut.com/2009/07/face-detection-in-orkut-photo-albums.html).

Please help me to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705403/net-face-recognition-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use OpenCV, or more specifically, a C# wrapper library for OpenCV.

I *think* you can implement some (very) basic face detection using O[penCVDotNet](http://code.google.com/p/opencvdotnet/), although you should be aware that I don't think it's actively being developed. I just noticed I'm still on the list as a project committer, but I haven't done any work on it for a long time (if ever, can't remember why I got added in the first place).

You should probably go with [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), which is a much better C# wrapper for OpenCV. It is actively developed, and is compatible with OpenCV 2.0, and has a wider community surrounding it, and the documentation is good enough that you can easily get face detection working pretty quickly.